# Can I use .fakes file to speed compile time?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-fakes

Including large libraries takes a long time generating a huge obj\Debug\Fakes\nycbmcs\f.cs.

I know I can limit the scope of the fakes by

```
<StubGeneration>
<Clear />
<Add Namespace="My.Huge.Assembly.MyNamespace!" />
</StubGeneration>
```

Referencing anything outside My.Huge.Assembly.MyNamespace will cause a compile error, however it still generates the same sized .cs file and takes just as long.

There is a FakesAssemblies*.fakesconfig that appears to list everything that gets generated, however if I edit it, it gets overwritten.

I do realize I can save the assembly and/or the other files that get generated, but this is a less than ideal solution.  I have to worry about copying them between machines, and occasionally do need to generate one, which takes forever.

Answer (score 0):

Both

```
<StubGeneration>
    <Clear />
</StubGeneration>
```

and

```
<ShimGeneration>
    <Clear />
</ShimGeneration>
```

are required to avoid importing default fakes for everything.  Just including StubGeneration, for example, means it will generate all possible shims.